# Reenable Move Warning for Active Directory Objects

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Was moving around some AD objects and accidentally clicked the "Do not show this warning again" For moving AD objects...

I like this warning as it is a final step to confirm that I actually want to perform this operation.

Anyone know how to reenable the warning? Could not find that inside any options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a per session checkbox so restarting ADUC should restore the warning.

Comment: Perfect! HAHA would have figured that out next time I logged on :) Will accept as soon as it allows me to. Please mark up if you felt this question was useful and clear